# How to configure PostgreSQL to accept specific IPV6 incoming connection

Tags: linux, postgresql

I'm trying to connect to my remote DB from inside Intellij.

So I think I need to be in pg_hba.conf

I have my IPV4 local connections:

```
host all all my.IP.V4.ip/32 md5
```

Question: beneath this is a line to configure IPV6, I have the address but I don't know what exactly to put for the IPV6 line after the "/"? Do I even need the slash?

```
host  all  all   1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8/???  md5
```

UPDATE: Hmm, so I have...

```
host   all  all  xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:ccc:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/128 trust
```

...and my db client (intellij) is still asking for a username / password.

user:postgres....pass:none....is still failing

thanks in advance

Comment: P.S.: This question really belongs to [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com).  You may want to close-vote and ask for a migration; I only just realised that after I had answered it :( ...

Comment: Oh...how do I ask for a migration?

Comment: I created a question there as well....https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/301731/how-to-configure-postgresql-to-accept-specific-ipv6-incoming-connection

Comment: Perhaps you didn't reload PostgreSQL. Perhaps there is an earlier `pg_hba.conf` entry that already matches the incoming connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_hba.conf` takes CIDR addresses, so yes, just like with IPv4 address you'll need the slash and the number behind it.

If you want to narrow the permissible connection down to one specific host you'll want to specify a `/128`.

```
host  all  all   1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8/128  md5
```

Comment: Hmm, so I have 
```
host    all   all   xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:ccc:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/128  trust
```
and my db client (intellij) is still asking for a username / password. .. user:postgres....pass:none....is still failing

Comment: @thefonso Did you restart the service after the change?

Comment: @thefonso - and how are you connecting?

Comment: @thefonso - can you connect using `psql` on the command line?

Comment: I rebooted the remote server. I'm attempting to connect to the remote PG from inside my local machines Datagrip (which is part of Intellij)

Comment: @thefonso Can you please try using `psql`? I don't know/have your tooling and can't confirm how it's supposed to behave.

Comment: I got it...this was the solution